# How to eager fetch join table collection in Hibernate Native SQL Query?

Tags: sql, hibernate, native

I have following three database tables

1. Customer
2. Product
3. CustomerProductRelation

Corresponding to these tables, I have two Hibernate POJO's

1. Product
2. Customer

One of the member variable is a joinTable:

```
@JoinTable(name = "CustomerProductRelation", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "CUSTOMER_ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "PRODUCT_ID") })
private List<Product> products;
```

Due to some reason, I need to use a native SQL query on Customer table, in that case how do I eager fetch products in my customer list?

I am doing something similar to this:

```
String queryString = "select c.*,cpr.product_id from Customer c, CustomerProductRelation cpr where c.customer_id = cpr.customer_id";
List list = getSession().createSQLQuery(queryString)
                .addEntity("c", Customer.class)
                .addJoin("p", "c.products").list();
```

This does not seem to work. The exception is as follows:

`java.lang.NullPointerException at org.hibernate.loader.DefaultEntityAliases.<init>(DefaultEntityAliases.java:37) at org.hibernate.loader.ColumnEntityAliases.<init>(ColumnEntityAliases.java:16) at org.hibernate.loader.custom.sql.SQLQueryReturnProcessor.generateCustomReturns(SQ‌​LQueryReturnProcessor.java:264)`

Please let me know if anyone knows the solution to this.

Comment: When you see 'it does not seem to work'. What do you mean? Exceptions? Unexpected results?

Comment: I am getting following exception java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.hibernate.loader.DefaultEntityAliases.<init>(DefaultEntityAliases.java:37)
 at org.hibernate.loader.ColumnEntityAliases.<init>(ColumnEntityAliases.java:16)
 at org.hibernate.loader.custom.sql.SQLQueryReturnProcessor.generateCustomReturns(SQLQueryReturnProcessor.java:264)

Answer (score 1):

Is [this](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-2225) what you are seeing? (HHH-2225)

Comment: Thanks Alex. It seems this issue is still open. Any alternatives ?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know of one. Sorry I can't be more help. The issue didn't describe one either. Just a lot of frustration.

Comment: Happy for you to go ahead and do that if you have the time to do the edit. Hibernate's Jira project is probably pretty stable and not prone to change.